# UniqueConstraint on dataset fails when values contain space

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable in which one of the columns has string values. I want to enforce an unique constraint on that column, but the constraint fails if I have two values that differ only by a space at the end (like "test" and "test "). I don't want this, I want the two values to be considered unique even if the only difference is a space at the end. How can I do this?

```
try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("test");
                dt.Columns.Add("nr");
                dt.Columns.Add("text");
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 1, "test" };
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 2, "test " };
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 3, "alabala" };
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 4, "bbb" };
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet("testds");
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                ds.EnforceConstraints = true;
                UniqueConstraint unqUID = new UniqueConstraint(ds.Tables[0].Columns[1], true);
                ds.Tables[0].Constraints.Add(unqUID);

                int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is anything you can do with this I'm afraid.

It just seems to discount the space at the end of the string. If you place a space at the beginning of the the second row like this :- " test". It Includes the space and determines the two rows as Unique.

I'd be interested to find out if a solution exists, but I cant find one.